# Best Practice for GIT Submodule between DEV and PRODUCTION

Tags: git

I know this has been dealt with by others, but I've found it difficult to locate a best practice on using GIT as a package manager to keep a DEV and PROD synchronized.  Most of the solutions are for specific portions of this cycle.

Answer (score 1):

This is our environment

```
/dev/public_repo/.git # package-xxx
/dev/public_repo/submodule/.git # vendor-package

/production/public_repo/.git # package-xxx
/production/public_repo/submodule/.git # vendor-package
```

As development progresses across deployments, changes need to be imported.  Each first level submodule is actively monitored. We loop a `git pull` on each submodule within the package:

```
cd /dev/public_repo/
for repo in *; 
  do if [ -d "$repo" ]; then 
    cd "$repo"
    git pull
  fi
done
```

This pulls only the first level packages. Recursive / nested submodules are examined individually for upstream changes to vendor submodules.  We make any submodule changes and push them to their respective submodule branch.

```
cd /dev/public_repo/submodule/
git add .
git commit -m "Made Changes"
git push
```

We then push the changes to the package repository.

```
cd /dev/public_repo/
git add . 
git commit -m "Upstream Changes"
git push
```

At this point we are ready to deploy.  From the PRODUCTION repository we should have no changes to the submodules, and are pulling down the state from the package repository.

```
cd /production/public_repo/
git pull
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

If trash has collected in the any /production/ submodule (not recursively) preventing a `fast-forward` then we run `git clean -fd` in a loop:

```
cd /dev/public_repo/
for repo in *; 
  do if [ -d "$repo" ]; then 
    cd "$repo"
    git clean -fd
  fi
done
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

After this `git status` should show a clean repository, and the production package should be up to date.

If at this point you realize PRODUCTION is broken and you need to revert to the previous state you would run something like this.

```
cd /production/public_repo/
git reset HEAD~2
git submodule update
```

This will reset the PRODUCTION repository to the second to last commit, then synchronize each submodule to the state of that commit. *This has not been fully tested with 2+ level submodules.*

Any feedback is appreciated.